# Truncate on foreign table

Tags: postgresql

I use postgresql_fdw on postgresql 9.3.3.

This is what I have:

SERVER_A:

```
SERVER_A=> CREATE TABLE table_a (
SERVER_A(>   id integer,
SERVER_A(>   val varchar(10)
SERVER_A(> );
SERVER_A=> INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (1, "a");
INSERT 0 1
```

SERVER_ACTIVE:

```
SERVER_ACTIVE=> CREATE FOREIGN TABLE table_a (
SERVER_ACTIVE(>  id integer,
SERVER_ACTIVE(>  val varchar(10)
SERVER_ACTIVE(> ) SERVER SERVER_A;
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE
```

Now I check the elements.

```
SERVER_ACTIVE=> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_a;
 count
-------
     1
(1 row)
```

Now I want to truncate the table:

```
ACC_ACTIVE=> TRUNCATE TABLE table_a;
ERROR:  "table_a" is not a table
ACC_ACTIVE=> TRUNCATE FOREIGN TABLE table_a;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FOREIGN"
LINE 1: TRUNCATE FOREIGN TABLE table_a;
```

Why doesn't it work? How do I make it work? This table is supposed to hold several millions of records, I can't use `DELETE`. But even if I `DELETE`, I can't use `VACUUM`.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/postgres-fdw.html) doesn't mention anything about the ability to `TRUNCATE` remote tables. (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` are listed as the available commands.) As a workaround, you could use [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/contrib-dblink-function.html).

Answer (score 2):

Document is quite clear https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html. It says:

> Now you need only SELECT from a foreign table to access the data stored in its underlying remote table. You can also modify the remote table using INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE. (Of course, the remote user you have specified in your user mapping must have privileges to do these things.)

In short, postgres_fwd does not support `TRUNCATE` on a remote (foreign) table.

You may use `DELETE FROM table`; which deletes all rows in the table. It recreates `TRUNCATE TABLE table` in the context of deleting data from a remote (foreign) table.

I felt the above answer was a bit brief so I elucidated.